# programatically passing an element to a function in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<div id='one'>one</div>
<div id='two'>two</div>

function Red(e)
{
  $(e.target).css('color','red');  
}
```

//
if i bind an event click to div='one' with fn "Red", function "Red" will receive e="div one",
now i want to bind some event on div=two so that it send div=one to function Red.

remember: i don't want to bind any event to div=one

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the question at all.

Comment: You want to be able to click on div "two" and have div "one" referenced in the "Red" method?

Comment: @David read WVDominick's comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#two').click(function(){
    Red({target: $('#one')[0]});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#two').bind('click', function () {
  e.target = $('#one');
  return Red(e);
});
```

but this is not really great, maybe you could modify your Red function to that:

```
function Red(el)
{
  $(el).css('color','red');  
}
$('#two').bind('click', function () {
  return Red($('#one'));
});
```

Comment: i dont want to just change color your above code somewhat closer to my requirement

Answer (score -3):

If all your `div`s have the `id` attribute set, why not just do `$('#one')` to retrieve the `div` in your function?

Comment: It is very very wrong for multiple elements to have the same "id" value.

Comment: @michael  i have written this just for readability exact requirement is a bit complex

Comment: Yes, I understand multiple elements should not have the same `id`. I'm not sure how my answer suggested this.